# values in my select option value isn't selected even though I made them selected in my code

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I hope someone from you here can read my code `crimes` and `criminal` value there are actually props, I just separated them so that I can just show their values..

My goal is to highlight all the crimes in the option value and put their respective crime descriptions in the textbox beside it just like this

[image: form values]

This is my code..

```html
<div v-if="input.crimes.length">
            <div v-for="(crime, index) in input.crimes" :key="index">
                <div class="flex w-full inline-block">
                    <select class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal w-1/5" v-model="crime.id"> 
                        <option class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal" v-for="option in crimeTypes" :value="option.id" :key="option.id">{{ option.criminal_offense }}</option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lightest w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal w-1/3" type="text" v-model="crime.comment"/>
                    <span class="ml-2"><button @click="$delete(input.crimes, index)"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <input type="text" v-model="crime.description"> -->
        </div>

        <!-- if there is none then just display the textbox -->
        <div v-else>
            <h3>There are no crimes for this guy</h3>
        </div>
```

These are the data that I was using

```js
data(){
        return {
            input: {
                crimes : this.criminal.crimes,
    }
},
methods :{ 
addNewCrime() {
            this.input.crimes.push({ id: 1, description : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." });
},
},

computed : { 
    crimeTypes(){ return this.crimes } 
},
```

These are the values that I have in my vue instance. I just separated these two since it's more compact to just separate them from the vue instance.. `crimes` and `criminals` are separate. The crimeTypes value is just the same as the crimes value here. they're very vital

`crimes:`

```
[{"criminal_offense":"Kidnapping"},{"criminal_offense":"Armed Robbery"},{"criminal_offense":"Arson"},{"criminal_offense":"Drug Trafficking"},{"criminal_offense":"Terrorism"},{"criminal_offense":"Extortion"},{"criminal_offense":"Human Trafficking"}]
```

`criminal` :

```
{"id":1,"full_name":"Sadye Walker","alias":"Gunner","first_name":"Sadye","middle_name":"Rau","last_name":"Walker","created_at":"2019-08-20 19:44:34","updated_at":"2019-08-20 19:44:34","status":"1","posted_by":1,"photo":"1577724169.jpeg","country_id":388,"contact_number":"911","profile":{"criminal_id":1,"birthplace":"19225 Grayce Ville\nNew Mitchel, GA 69927-8941","country_last_seen":400,"birthdate":"1983-05-09 00:00:00","last_seen":"58159 Thomas Hollow\nEast Vidaview, UT 43803-2557","eye_color":"gray","weight_in_kilos":"60","height_in_feet_and_inches":"5'8","country_of_origin":"862","body_frame":"skinny","bounty":"7269.39","created_at":"2019-08-22 04:39:48","updated_at":"2019-08-22 04:39:48","complete_description":"Fill all description of the criminal that are not listed above such as :1. Height :&nbsp;2. Weight3. Eye Color4. Body Frame5. Any other details","currency":"TTD"},"country":{"id":388,"capital":"Kingston","citizenship":"Jamaican","country_code":"388","currency":"Jamaica dollar","currency_code":"JMD","currency_sub_unit":"cent","currency_symbol":"$","currency_decimals":2,"full_name":"Jamaica","iso_3166_2":"JM","iso_3166_3":"JAM","name":"Jamaica","region_code":"019","sub_region_code":"029","eea":0,"calling_code":"1","flag":"JM.png"},"crimes":[{"id":2,"criminal_offense":"Armed Robbery","description":"I should like to have it explained,' said the Mock Turtle. 'She can't explain it,' said.","pivot":{"criminal_id":1,"crime_id":2,"crime_description":"Dicta consequuntur voluptas porro et veniam ut culpa eos dolorem."}},{"id":4,"criminal_offense":"Drug Trafficking","description":"The Dormouse again took a minute or two to think about stopping herself before she found.","pivot":{"criminal_id":1,"crime_id":4,"crime_description":"Explicabo et et quam et est accusantium sit sed omnis."}}]}
```

It's ok since the number of values here are correct.. for these specific criminal he has 2 crimes.

Updates...[ here ]

[image]

I already got it right here since the two crimes were already correctly highlighted but the values inside those select boxes are repeating so the values of those two are just the same.. It's repeating.

I used it like this

```html
    <div v-if="input.crimes.length">
            <div v-for="(crime, index) in input.crimes" :key="index">
                <div class="flex w-full inline-block">
                    <select class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal w-1/3">
                        <option class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal" v-for="(option,index) in crimeTypes" :value="crime.id" :key="">
                            {{ option.criminal_offense }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lightest w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal w-1/2" type="text" v-model="crime.description"/>
                    <span class="ml-2"><button @click="$delete(input.crimes, index)"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <input type="text" v-model="crime.description"> -->
        </div>

        <!-- if there is none then just display the textbox -->
        <div v-else>
            <h3>There are no crimes for this guy</h3>
        </div>

        <span>
            <button class="bg-blue-dark text-white p-3 mb-2" @click.prevent.stop="addNewCrime()">Add new Crime
            </button>
        </span>
```

Comment: Missing brace in `data()`

Comment: don't mind the minor mistakes.. Those are small ones.

Comment: crimes do not have the id prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `criminal_offense` instead of `id`. Because the crime type has no `id` prop.

```
<select class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal w-1/5" v-model="crime.criminal_offense">
  <option class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal" v-for="option in crimeTypes" :value="option.criminal_offense" :key="option.criminal_offense">{{ option.criminal_offense }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My answer is still valid.